# JS Import Not working with Prepros App

Tags: javascript

I have 2 js files with the below code

index.js

```
import Alert from './source1'

( ($) => {
    const version = $.fn.jquery.split( ' ' )[ 0 ].split( '.' )
} )( $ )

export {
    Alert,
}
```

And 
source1.js

```
const Alert = ( ($) => {
    class Alert {
        constructor(element) {
            this._element = element
        }
    }

    return Alert
} )( $ )

export default Alert
```

When i compile index.js with babel in prepros app. 
I am getting the below compiled code

```
'use strict';

Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", {
    value: true
});
exports.Alert = undefined;

var _source = require('./source1');

var _source2 = _interopRequireDefault(_source);

function _interopRequireDefault(obj) { return obj && obj.__esModule ? obj : { default: obj }; }

(function ($) {
    var version = $.fn.jquery.split(' ')[0].split('.');
})($);

exports.Alert = _source2.default;
```

From the compiled source i can see that source1.js is not getting combined.

Comment: Please add your babel config file

Comment: Sorry i am new to this. babel thing. so i dont have any config. can you please guide me ?